# Como acessar os índices de um vetor muito grande em C?

Tags: c, array

Estou com um problema que tenho que montar um vetor (`vet2[50]`) com a soma de um vetor grande (`vet1[100]`), esse vetor `vet1` é fornecido pelo usuário e a soma se da por:

```
vet2[0]=vet1[0]+vet1[1]

vet2[1]=vet1[2]+vet1[3]
.
.
.
vet2[49]=vet1[98]+vet1[99]
```

Não consigo estabelecer uma lógica para fazer essa soma, se os vetores fossem menores daria pra fazer manual (método acima), mas como são grandes estou meio perdida.

Comment: Esse vetor é minúsculo. Precisaria de mais informações. Seria bom colocar seu código na pergunta e dizer onde está tendo problema. Mas qualquer tamanho não faz sentido fazer um por um.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Precisa fazer um laço e variar o índice pela variável do laço.

Eu fiz um exemplo com 6 números, mas é só mudar para 100 na segunda linha. Não coloque um valor ímpar que vai dar problema.

Iniciei os vetores zerando eles, fiz um laço para ler todos itens, depois fiz o laço da soma e finalmente o laço mostrando o resultado.

No laço de soma criei cada elemento do segundo vetor somando os elementos equivalentes de acordo com a fórmula aparentemente pedida na pergunta (não é fácil fazer algo sem uma definição de fórmula, mas estou confiante que é isso que deseja).

Para um exercício acho que está bom assim.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 6

int main(void) {
    int vet1[MAX];
    int vet2[MAX / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) scanf("%d", &vet1[i]);
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX / 2; i++) vet2[i] = vet1[i * 2] + vet1[i * 2 + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX / 2; i++) printf("%d\n", vet2[i]);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/3O9HIk). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/qddlzqdf-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/Large.c).